# Rich Client/Java EE server best practices?

Tags: jakarta-ee, gwt, ejb, dao, rich-client-platform

I am looking for some suggestions on re-architecture of a 2EE app which seems to me overly complex, and I'm wondering if there are simpler ways of doing this. The architecture is as follows:

- browser-based client using GWT
- GWT RPC Asynchronous interface
- GWT Remote Service Servlet
- Business delegate layer
- Stateless EJB (EJB 2.0 spec!)
- DAO  (uses iBatis framework)
- Database

Our application is a client/server type of app with a rich client interface - not unique, I'm sure. Are there not simpler ways of implementing a rich client, where you also want a bunch of work done on the server, avoiding lots of round trips? What are best practices/tools for such a design?

Thanks

Comment: This stack seems very similar to what we use at work. We have a very large enterprise system and it seems to work reasonably well.

Answer (score 0):

Your stack layer is not that bad. We have GWT RPC over Business Layer built on Hibernate DAO accessing database. We are delivering a enterprise application with more than 100 screens with decent performance and complexity.

Your alternate for RPC - [RequestFactory](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory) , [JSON with RequestBuilder](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/JSON)

Your alternate for server side stack - Hibernate with RF or Hibernate with Dozer & RPC.

RequestFactory has the least amount of data footprint over network but high complexity w.r.t to learning curve. We would like to move to RF but its just damn hard to learn !!!